# Intl.NumberFormat: difference between currency and number

Tags: javascript

Why is the output with Intl.NumberFormat different when using style: 'currency' than when just formatting a regular number?

For some reason when formatting as currency it uses different comma-point seperator rules when using the same locale.

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-BE').format(2222.22))
// 2.222,22
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-BE', {
  currency: 'EUR',
  style: 'currency'
}).format(2222.22))
// €2,222.22 -> I expect €2.222,22
```

Comment: If I use `de-DE` I get `2.222,22` for both; if I use `en-US` I get `2,222.22` for both. However [en-BE](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-BE/index.html) lists the comma as decimal separate for both numbers and currency...

Comment: @ChrisG So what are you saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would get the same issues with en-DE

If you want European format use valid locales.

- nl_NL, nl-BE, de-BE (€ 2.222,22)
- fr-BE (2 222,22 €)

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL').format(2222.22))
// 2.222,22

const opts = {
  currency: 'EUR',
  style: 'currency'
}

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', opts).format(2222.22))
// € 2.222,22 

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-BE', opts).format(2222.22))
// 2 222,22 €
```

Comment: So you are saying that en-BE is not a valid locale?

Comment: @thijscrombeen Yes.  There are 3 valid Belgian locales. de/nl/fr-BE

Comment: Why not just `nl-NL`?

Comment: Made more sense when I wanted to show an fr version. OP used _BE - See update